# What structure should I use for an approval workflow?

Tags: lotus-notes

This is a common problem that I find when programming a Lotus Notes App.

Use case: An employer fills out a request form in a Request database. A notification gets mailed to the person that may give them OK or REJECT for that request. The authority person visits the Request database and gives OK or REJECT.

Good. But, where would you save the approval status OK or REJECT:

- Should the authority person have write access to the original request
  and set the status directly (and may alter other data in the form)
- Should the aproval action create a response doc to the original (and i cannot show in a view the current status)

Comment: Have a look at Lotus Workflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you are better off setting an approval status directly on the request.  That may not seem initially ideal, but remember Lotus Notes isn't like a relational database where things would be more normalized.

Let's consider the alternative, putting a status in the response document.  Now how do you show all the requests with their statuses?  You'd probably have to write some code just to do that when with the first option you could just create a view.

You can control the access to the document using reader and writer access fields.  See how the built in template does it (the approval workflow template).  Essentially as the document changes state (i.e. New, Submitted for Approval, Approved or Denied, etc), you can also change the reader and writer access fields at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Once, I designed a database that mailed that request to the approver with the form stored in the document. As long as the user accessed the document using a Notes client, they could click on a button in the message to approve, which would send a message back to the database with the field data to mark the request as approved. An agent in that request database was set to run when new mail arrived, read those messages and change status on the original requests. That way, the approver never had to leave their inbox and didn't even need rights to edit the request.

You could do it with URLs if the users would be approving via browser client - have the link to an agent and pass in the parameters.

Or, to go back to your scenario, once the requester has submitted the request, don't display the fields that you don't want changed, display the values as computed text instead.

Anyway you look at it, best to have the approval recorded on the original document.

Answer (score 0):

For above, Everything is our concern. In SQL or any other RDMS, we are in need of normalize that. Similarly here we have view categorization, show response document in hierarchy, and a lot of great hide when functionality based on role, ACL, unique person and whatever you need. We can easily manipulate the data render depends on the current user.

For your Q:-
1. We can control the appropriate user[authority person] from editing the request form's item.
2. We can also do by the response document. There we can show the documents in view by using show the Response documents in hierarchy.